# Using mean value theorem to prove inequality

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, inequality

I need to show, using the Mean Value Theorem, that $\forall k \geq 2$:
$$\frac{1}{k}<\log k-\log (k-1)<\frac{1}{k-1}$$

> 

Since $f(x)=\log x$ is continuous on $[k-1, k]$ and differentiable on $(k-1, k)$, by the MVT there is some $c \in(k-1, k)$ such that
$$
\log k-\log (k-1)=f^{\prime}(c)(k-(k-1))=\frac{1}{c}
$$
Now $c \in(k-1, k)$, so  $$k-1<c<k$$ and $$\frac{1}{k} < \frac{1}{c} = f^{\prime}(c) < \frac{1}{k-1}$$
$$
\frac{1}{k}<\log k-\log (k-1)<\frac{1}{k-1}
$$

This inequaliy is only defined for  $k \geq 2$.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Is there a reason you're posting it?

Comment: I had a question, which I just edited out ... regarding why it holds for $k\geq2$ part. I guess I should close it, right ?

Comment: Is there anything else to say other than the inequality is not defined below 2 ?

Comment: Well, if you don't restrict $k$ to be an integer, then you need $k-1$ to be in the domain of $\log$, so you need $k>1$. It in fact holds for all real numbers $k>1$.